# Voltdb node failed when the RAM is about 10G

Tags: voltdb

I am trying to use voltdb. The capacity of the vm is 16U with 32G RAM. But I specified the xmx with 6G. The node failed when I trying to dump data into the voltdb. I calculated the size of the data following the official document. it is about 500M. But the process takes up about 10G RAM and it failed. Anyone knows the reason?

comment: I am using the default configuration of voltdb and running it in docker.

Answer (score 2):

VoltDB dev here. Without looking at the log files, it is hard to say what the root cause was. The tail of the log file usually includes error messages that indicate why the cluster has gone down. If you can post the log file, we can take a look and help you pinpoint the issue. If you want, you can also post on our public forum at https://forum.voltdb.com or join our Slack channel at http://chat.voltdb.com/.

Ning

Comment: I checked the log. Seems no more useful messages in the console.

Comment: I have fixed the problem.  There is a larger loop in my procedure(add about 100,000 records).  I think  it will be better to replace fail the DB with fail the procedure.